# How to run app in background forever?

Tags: ios

I am testing my app and this will never be submitted to the iOS store. How to get the app to run forever in the background? I have set the Required Background Modes item 0 to voip but it still closes after sometime.

Comment: what exactly do you want to run in the background

Comment: @Konsy My app runs through a set of locations through a GPX file but it stops randomly and I never reach the destination which is often an hour or more away

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is to trick the system into thinking that the app is always doing something. A good example would be to have an audio file constantly playing which is allowed so that things like podcast players can work in the background. The audio file could be silent in this case. I believe this was the trick that Facebook used when their app was eating everyone's batteries, but don't quote me on that. The only potential downsides would be that it could clash with other audio playback and it might use a lot of battery.